# Change intent bundle data before an activity is re-created after orientation change

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I have a notification that starts my activity and passes a messages using the intent's  putExtra() function. The message is then displayed to the user in the activity's onCreate function. When the application is restarted due to a orientation change, the message is shown again as it is still in the intent's bundled data.

How can I remove the extra data?

I tried the following:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle.getBoolean("showMessage")) {
    // ... show message that is in bundle.getString("message")
    // remove message
    bundle.remove("showMessage");
}
```

But the message will still be shown after the orientation changed, seems like the intent used is not the one I changed, but the original one. The only workaround I found is to save the showMessage additionally in o`nSaveInstanceState()`.
Is there another way? Or is this the way to go?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The (simple) solution is:

Instead of calling

```
bundle.remove("showMessage");
```

I now use

```
getIntent().removeExtra("showMessage");
```

which works as expected. Seems like getIntent().getExtras() returns a copy, not a reference.

Comment: Sorry, -1. `onSaveInstanceState` is the right way to do this, as pointed out by @CommonsWare.

Answer (score 10):

Your `onSaveInstanceState()` approach is the correct answer, AFAIK.